# After an update I can't get pass the log in screen and the resolution is changed

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, login, display-resolution

I'm using a computer at my work place and did a full day of work without problem. Before I left I accepted an update which was downloaded and installed. I shut down the computer and went home.

When I came in today the login screen felt different. The resultion was much lower. And then I noticed that I could not log in (as netiher guest, testuser or my root user). The screen flashes some and the jumps back to the login screen.

Something to do with my graphics card? Or perhaps a virus?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS trusty.

Edit: Added the output of:

`$ lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'`

```
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 11b4 (rev a1)
        Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1096
04:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

Also, graphical programs work when I ssh to the computer from my laptop, but not when trying to run them on the computer from the ctr+alt+f1 promt.

Comment: Did you install an Nvidia driver? How did you do it?

Comment: I did not install that myself, the IT guy did. He did however use NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-352.21.run. I can access the prompt by ctr+alt+f1 and I did sudo nvidia-installer --update and was told I already had the latest version.

Comment: You installed the driver a wrong way. Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You or someone else installed an Nvidia driver a wrong way.

After each kernel upgrade it stops working.

You can install same driver from ppa. In this case it will stay permanently. Run in terminal the commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

and reboot

Comment: Thanks! That actually did it!
What did we do differently now, from what he probably did? Thank you so much!! :)

Comment: @Robin The first time the driver has been installed form a file downloaded from Nvidia site. It has not been registered with DKMS. It was not built for the new kernel. Now it is OK.